# Mocking useSelector doesn't work when updating from react 16 to 17

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am mocking useSelector:

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
    useDispatch: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('../../../app/slices/authenticateSlice');

const createWrapper = (state) => {
    getLoginRequest.mockReturnValue(state);
    return shallow(<Login /> )
}
```

Everything is working fine with create-react-app and react 16 version, but when I update from:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
```

to

```
"@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

it gives me

```
Cannot destructure property 'isLoading' of '(0 , _reactRedux.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

at

```
const {isLoading, error} = useSelector(getLoginRequest);
```

Also I have a setup that is next.js not create-react-app with @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.3 and react 17 and the tests there are working. Any ideas where it can come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you can configure your mock function to inject test values into your code during test.

```js
const mockFunc = jest.fn();

mockFunc.mockReturnValueOnce({isLoading: true, error: null});
```

Then use it as follows

```js
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    useSelector: mockFunc,
    useDispatch: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Further reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions